# UITableview Edit/delate- cell's content goes out of screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview

All,
I am using **UITableview** and trying to implement an **edit/delete** function.

When I call this line .

```
  [tblStoreAvail setEditing:TRUE animated:TRUE];
```

The cell's content goes out of screen.

These functions are never called.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

[image: UITableView Cell content goes out of screen]

Comment: instead of adding Right label as subview.. set the label as accessoryView and EditingAccessoryView..
 cell.editingAccessoryView = label;
    cell.accessoryView = label;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custuomTableViewCell implement the following method with your required frame for the label:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state]; 
if(state == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask)
    {
        [self.lblLocation setFrame:CGRectMake(13,22,302,21)];
    }
    else if(state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
    {
        [self.lblLocation setFrame:CGRectMake(13,22,245,21)]; 
    }
    else if(state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
    {
        [self.lblLocation setFrame:CGRectMake(13,22,245,21)]; 
    }
    else
    {
        [self.lblLocation setFrame:CGRectMake(13,22,210,21)];  
    }
}
```

if you are using default TableViewCell then make sure to set delegate for tableView and do like below :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 yourCustomCell *cell = (yourCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.lblLocation setFrame:CGRectMake(13,22,302,21)];
    return  YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems going on, Taimur.

1) you need to set the "`delegate`" of your table to whatever object (presumably your view controller) that holds those delegate methods.  You can do this programmatically or via a connection in the XIB / storyboard.

2) if you're using a custom cell, you need to adjust the font sizes down to hold all the data you want to display.

If you're not using custom UITableViewCell objects to display the data in your table, then start to use them so you can get the formatting you really want to see.